# Do Not Fire function after page reload - Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

```php
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'orderReceived' );
function orderReceived($order_id)
{
    $order = wc_get_order($order_id);

    if (!$order->has_status('failed') && did_action('woocommerce_thankyou') === 1) {
        addPoints(1000, 'add', 'order');
    }
}
```

How can I make sure the above function fires only once on the woocommerce thankyou page?

At the moment it fires everytime I reload the thank you page. This means that someone can get infinite points.

Comment: Can one person earn multiple points if they place multiple orders?

Comment: Yes, but not multiple points per the same order

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use order meta data to check whether the points is added already or not.

Try out this code :-

```
$points_check = $order->get_meta('_points_added');

If($points_check != 'added'){
$order->update_meta_data( '_points_added', 'added' );
 $order->save();
addPoints(1000, 'add', 'order');
}
```

Comment: just tried this. you forgot to add $order->save(). but that works perfectly!! thank you so much

Comment: Ohh it's my bad Because I've added the code from my mobile phone so  i forgot about it.

Comment: Per the comment in the main question, you'll probably want to also store something about the specific order ID so that additional orders can receive points in the future.

Comment: since we are saving the metadata for a particular order so we don't need to store the order_id.

Comment: Sorry @zillionera_dev, I thought it was generic meta and didn't see it was order-specific!